# How to convert youtube api data to xml data feed using php?

Tags: php, json, xml, youtube

I have an idea to convert this JSON data:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=us&videoCategoryId=10&key=Mykey
```

to xml ,To use for feeds Rss reader

How to do this using PHP only ?

My respect

Comment: What steps have you taken to attempt to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube API only returns JSON. You can load the json in your code and implement your own XML using

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
// other headers are required
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";

echo '<xml>';
// Your data
echo '</xml>';
```

Comment: include output in your post